# Load UITableView From CSV Database File?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, csv

Is it possible to load a UITableView with a database in CSV format?  Or is there an easy way to convert this to a .plist first or something similar?  Any advice would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And if you want to know how to read a CSV file, I've written a library to do that:

https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser

Please remember that using it means you must abide by the license under which the code is made available.

Comment: +1, @Dave, I've used it with success. (The app is not done yet, but your library  in there. good stuff.)

Answer (score 1):

You can load UITableView using any sort of data you want. Just create a datasource that implements [UITableViewDataSource](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDataSource).

This documentation is also helpful: [Table View Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH6-SW5)